# How to redirect URL (Old to New) in php [laravel, htaccess]

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, laravel-5

Recently I changed my website corePHP to Laravel. So I have many old URls and I  want to  redirect them as new URLs.

My old URL- **www.xyz.com/ad_posted.php?title=pure-murra-buffalo-son-bharatpur-1476942104**

I want to new url like this - **www.xyz.com/cat/subcat/pure-murra-buffalo-son-bharatpur-1476942104**

I have code in route.php

```
Route::get('{uri}', function($uri){
    $title = Input::get('title');

    if(preg_match('ad_posted.php?title=', $uri) && isset($title)){
        return Redirect::to('www.xyz.com/cat/subcat/'.$title);
    }
    else{
        App::abort(404);
    }
})->where('all', '.*');
```

But it did not work.

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Is the client not redirected, or does the website crash or return 404, or anything else?

Comment: Yes, it not redirected, It is showing "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

Comment: It  fixed as answer given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that you wrote is the first Route rule, is a catch all route, so it can potentially catch *every* or nearly GET request. 
I would try to use a Route with a more specific rule, like that:

```
Route::get('ad_posted.php', function(){
    $tile = request('title');
    ....
});
```